Jolt Replacing substring within a string
I am retrieving the following json
{
  "value": [
    {
      "identifier": "first_path",
      "language": "",
      "product_no": "",
      "value": "MYPATH\\PATH01",
      "value_unit_key": ""
    },
    {
      "identifier": "e_class_number",
      "language": "",
      "product_no": "",
      "value": "40-02-90-01",
      "value_unit_key": ""
    },
    {
      "identifier": "erp_lastchange_at",
      "language": "",
      "product_no": "",
      "value": "17.07.2023 13:14:50",
      "value_unit_key": ""
    },
    {
      "identifier": "second_path",
      "language": "",
      "product_no": "",
      "value": "MYPATH\\PATH02",
      "value_unit_key": ""
    },
    {
      "identifier": "gross_weight",
      "language": "",
      "product_no": "",
      "value": "0.18",
      "value_unit_key": "kg"
    }
  ]
}

I would like to replace the backslash within the strings of the "value"- value, so that
"MYPATH\\PATH01" becomes "MYPATH||PATH01"
"MYPATH\\PATH02" becomes "MYPATH||PATH02"

etc.
I have already tried to do some split and join operations within jolt (modify-overwrite-json). But I did not manage to execute the replacement successfully.
I would be grateful, if anyone could give me a hint.
Thanks in advance

Yes, you were on the right track for the method but the backslashes are special type of characters and should be escaped by doubling them like in the following transformation that will handle your request :
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "value_": "=split('\\\\',@(1,value))",
          "value": "=join('||',@(1,value_))"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {//get rid of auxiliary attributes of name "value_"
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "value_": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

the demo on the site https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :


Amazing, thank you so much. This creating of a temporary value is a great idea!
